# Unable to LOOP for more than 1000 times in PostgreSQL(9.5.15) Procedure in order to insert the records

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, procedure

```
create or replace function createRows()
returns void as $$
DECLARE
r record;
BEGIN
FOR r IN 1..10000 LOOP
insert into rounds values(some values);
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Its inserting only 1000 records in the **rounds** table even if the specified range is greater than 1000 like 10,000/1,00,0000.

Comment: You don't need to write your own function for that. `insert into rounds (col) select i from generate_series(1,10000) i`

Comment: Works for me: https://rextester.com/YRP97592

Comment: @NickBarnes its not working on my system but it works fine on rextester.com/YRP97592

Comment: Please specify what your system is like (PostgreSQL version, OS, Managed Cloud System?), a more concrete `INSERT` statement (`some values` doesn't help in diagnosing) and the target table definition (including indexes).

Comment: @Gani: A [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) or [rule](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html) could cause inserts to be ignored. If you have either of those on your `rounds` table, you should include them in your question.